# Calculate Number of Trajectories

Tags: algebra-precalculus, permutations, combinations

> An object moves on a coordinate plane from point (0,0) to point
>   (15,11) in a series of steps, where each step increments one of the
>   two coordinates. How many different trajectories are possible?

I was given this question in an exam. I wrote 192 - turns out the answer is 7,726,160. God knows what I was thinking.

Can anybody explain to me how to solve this?

Comment: You have $11+15$ total moves to make...picking the "up" moves just means choosing $11$ of the available slots, so $\binom {11+15}{11}$.

Comment: @lulu, you should add some detail and write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Altogether, our object must make $11$ rightward and $15$ upward moves.  The order is unimportant...any combination will work.  To specify a path we just need to say which of the $26$ total moves are rightward (say).Thus, the problem comes down to the following:  "Given $11+15=26$ slots, how many ways are there to choose $11$ of them?"  Thus the answer to the question is $$\binom {26}{11}= 7,726,160$$